# Laravel : Why does this demo have to use compact()?

Tags: laravel

Laravel : Why does this demo have to use compact()?

demo:

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = user()->articles;

    $multiplied = $articles->map(function ($item, $key) {
        $item->tags = ['foo', 'bar'];
        return $item;
    });
    $newArticles = $multiplied->all();
    dd($newArticles); //this is an array
    return view('articles', compact('newArticles'));  //question here
}
```

result of `dd($newArticles)`：

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Article {#498 ▶}
  1 => Article {#501 ▶}
]
```

**question：**
`$newArticles` is already an array ,why deos it have to use compact()?

```
return view('articles', $newArticles); // Undefined variable: newArticles
```

Comment: you can pass it like this return view('articles', array('newArticles'=>$newArticles);

Comment: It doesn't "have to" use `compact`. The use of `compact` is merely cleaner and more readable than declaring an array in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

**1st:** why using compact ?

**Ans :**  It creates an array containing variables and their values.

**note :** compact() is `not a Laravel function`. It is a `PHP function.`

**Example 1**:

```
       $name ="myname";
       $age="12"
       $final = compact('name','age');
       print_r($final);
```

**OUTPUT 1:**

```
   Array
(
    [name] => myname
    [age] => 12
)
```

**In view** template you will access the value like below

```
    echo  $name;
    echo  $age;
```

**Note :** between the controller to view `extract` will do that job 
`extract` function uses `array keys` as `variable names` and `values` as `variable values`

**Example for Extract :**

```
<?php
    extract(Array('name' => 'myname','age' => '12'));
    echo $name;
    echo $age;
?>
```

**Example 2 :** you can also manually create the array like this

```
return view('articles', array('newArticles'=>$newArticles));
```

**In view** you will access the value like this

```
 print_r($newArticles);
```